# Please explain the difference

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

> i have a program about 2-D arrays
>
> base adress is `8678`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
 int arr[3][3]={
                 {83,8,43},
                 {73,45,6},
                 {34,67,9}
                 };
printf("%d ",&arr+1);  //points to 8696
printf("%d ",arr+1);   //points to 8684
return 0;
}
```

> what is the difference between `arr+1` and `&arr+1`?

Answer (score 9):

Well, they're different things.  `arr` decays in most contexts to a pointer to the first element of your array - that means a pointer to the first 3-element row in your 2D array: type `int (*)[3]`.  `arr + 1`, then, points to the second row in the array.

`&arr` is the address of the array itself (type `int (*)[3][3]`), so `&arr + 1` points to memory just past the end of the entirety of your 2D array.

You can confirm this behaviour easily by printing differently.  Specifically, printing the offsets to the new pointers rather than the values themselves will help clear things up.  The output from your program from these print statements:

```
printf("%ld\n",(intptr_t)(&arr+1) - (intptr_t)arr);
printf("%ld\n",(intptr_t)(arr+1) - (intptr_t)arr);
```

Will be the decimal offsets to `&arr+1` and `arr+1` respectively.  Here's the output from a test run I just made:

```
36
12
```

36 matches up: 3 rows × 3 columns × 4 bytes per entry = 36 bytes.  So does the 12: 1 row × 3 columns × 4 bytes per entry = 12 bytes.

Note - you're also printing pointers using `%d`, which is wrong.  You should probably be using `%p` for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out with the help of this equivalence: X[Y] === *(X+Y)

Since *(arr+1) === arr[1], arr+1 === &arr[1]

Similarly, &arr+1 === &((&arr)[1])

What is (&arr)[1]?  Well, (&arr)[0] === *&arr === arr,
that is, the 3x3 array itself, so (&arr)[1] is the 3x3 array following that,
and &arr+1 === &((&arr)[1]) is the address of the 3x3 array following &arr ... a pointer to the byte just past the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Arr+1 gives the next element in an array while &arr +1 gives the address of next array of integers

Answer (score -1):

array + 1 means the array[1] 's address and it costs 3 int memory.

&array + 1 means the address of array[0] add 1;

Comment: Wrong.  Try it out and you'll see. Or even just look at th OP's output, I guess.

Comment: Pool english make you misunderstand me.  array is a pointer that points the address of array, and (array + 1) is a pointer that points the address of array[1].    &array  is the address of array and then add 1.

Comment: Carl Norum, you misunderstand me.