# cannot understand addressing in 2d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

```
main()
{
    int a[3][2] = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
    {
        printf("%d", a[i][j]);
        printf("\t %d\n", &a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n%d", *(a+1));
    printf("\n%d", *a+1);
}
```

> the output of *(a+1) is different from *a+1.
>
> *(a+1) is pointing to 3 rd element whereas
>
> *a+1 is outputting the 2nd value

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857698/please-explain-the-difference) for a good explanation.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Comment: `*(a+1)` is printing the 3rd element for you because `sizeof(int *)` appears to be twice as large as `sizeof(int)` in your host environment. `*a+1` prints the second value only because it actually uses the first value (`*a` i.e. `1`) and adds `1` to it, which happens to yield the second value.

Comment: @veer: Each element of the array is an `int[2]`, not an `int*`.  As such, it is incremented by `sizeof(int[2])`, not `sizeof(int*)`

Comment: @veer 

int (*p)[2];
p = &a[0];
printf("%d\n", *(p+1));
printf("%d\n", (p+1));
why these two statements return same value

Comment: @minefield: `int (*p)[2]` declares a pointer to array of `int[2]`.  Knowing that, in addition to what I said in my response, you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 6):

> the output of *(a+1) is different from *a+1.

Yes, due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  `*a + 1` means...

> Dereference `a` (which returns an `int`) and add `1` to it.  Return the result (`2`)

However, `*(a + 1)` says...

> Add `1` to the *pointer* `a` and dereference it, i.e., get the value at the address `a + sizeof(int[2])`.

The "value* happens to be the first element of the second array.  Remember; adding *n* to a pointer type advances the address by *n elements*. In this case, each element is an array of `int` with two elements of its own.

That should answer the next two questions as well.  After reading up on operator precedence, start studying [pointer arithmetic](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arithmetic).

Answer (score 4):

C doesn't really have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays. `int a[3][2]` declares a 3-element array whose elements are 2-dimensional arrays of ints.

Arithmetic on pointers takes this into account, it increments by the size of the objects that the pointer points to. So `(a+1)` evaluates to the second element of `a`, which is a pointer to the array `{3, 4}`. Indirecting through this pointer gets you its first element, which is 3.

`*a` on the other hand, indirects through pointer to the first element of `a`, which evaluates to 1. Then when you add 1 to this, you get 2. It's not actually returning the 2nd element, it just looks like it because 1+1 = 2. Try changing your initialization to:

```
int a[3][2] = { {1,3},{5,7},{9,11}};
```

and your output will be 5 and 2.

Comment: C really does have two-dimensional arrays; the standard calls them that. They happen to be arrays of arrays.

Comment: And they work just like any other language's 2-d arrays if you stick to array indexing syntax and supply all the dimensions. But if you want to understand how they work when you treat them as pointers, or omit dimensions in in array indexing, you must treat them as arrays of arrays.

Comment: Ada, for example, distinguishes between 2-d arrays and arrays of arrays. The former are indexed as `Arr[I, J]`, and the latter as `Arr[I][J]`; the two are not interchangeable. As you know, C's indexing operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "when you treat them as pointers".

Comment: The OP is treating them as pointers by using explicit dereferencing and arithmetic, instead of array syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about operator precedence.  In the second case `*a+1` the unary operator `*` binds more than the binary operator `+`.  So, the operation is treated like adding one to the value pointed by `a`.

In the former case `*(a+1)`, you are addressing the next element pointed by `a` and dereferencing it to get its value.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,that's correct.
Because a 2D array represent an array of 1D arrays.In this case in 
`a[3][2] = { {1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}`,name of array ,that is **a** acts as zeroth element of array. Since zeroth element of our 2-D array is 1-D array of 2 integers{1,2}.Thus, `(a+1)` refers to address of first element of 2D array `{3,4}` and *(a+1) thus gives value at that address i.e 3. While,*a gives access to first element and than it increments it by one giving 2.