# Working of Pointers and Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for C.

**main.c**

```
int main()                          
{
    int arr[2][3] = { { 10, 20, 30 }, { 15, 25, 35 } };
    int **pArr = arr;

    printf("\n\n----SIZE OF----");
    printf("\nSizeOf(arr) = %d", sizeof(arr));
    printf("\nSizeOf(pArr) = %d", sizeof(pArr));

    printf("\n\n----DEREFERENCING THE ADDRESS----");
    printf("\narr = %d   *arr = %d   **arr = %d", arr, *arr, **arr);
    printf("\npArr = %d   *pArr = %d   **pArr = %d", pArr, *pArr, **pArr);    //EXCEPTION thrown here

    return 0;
}
```

Check out this image for a thrown exception:

[image: Exception]

On using the break-point the values in pointer `pArr` & array `arr` are shown:

[image: On debugging]

But when I removed the `**pArr` part from the second last line of the code, the program output this:

```
----SIZE OF----
SizeOf(arr) = 24
SizeOf(pArr) = 4

----DEREFERENCING THE ADDRESS----
arr = 5569760   *arr = 5569760   **arr = 10
pArr = 5569760   *pArr = 10
```

Pointer `pArr` is of type "pointer to pointer to int", and therefore is the address at `arr`. Then why can't I access `**pArr` after using `int **pArr = arr;`?

Comment: Visual Studio is a C++ compiler, by the way. For this limited subset of the language, it won't matter, but you should be aware of that anyway.

Comment: How did `int **pArr = arr` even compile?  A 2D array does not decay into a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @jamesdlin I was also expecting an error but candidly speaking, it did compile. And I have no idea why is it behaving in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 1-D array,  `arr` it is pointer to base value of array arr. That is it is as good as `&arr[0]`.

When you use 2-D array arr represents pointer to base value, that is `arr[0]` which is `(*arr)[3]`.

So you should use,

```
int (*pArr)[3] = arr;
```

Instead of

```
int **ptr = arr;
```

Comment: Using `int **pArr = arr;`, where `arr` is a 2D Array, is not allowed?

Comment: No, because where you are pointing? Pointer to address of array. That means &arr? No we want to point to arr[0].

Comment: I must use `int **pArr = &arr;` instead of `int **pArr = arr;`, is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: @beginner No, that I am not suggesting that. First of all what is arr, in scene of pointer, it is pointer to 1-D array. So int (*ptr)[NUMBER], here you can point to `NUMBER` elements.

Comment: So, when I do `int **pArr = arr;` what actually goes in `pArr` is `*arr`.

Comment: @beginner Yes true. But when `int **ptr` is possible? When you hold address of pointer of int.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because `*pArr` yields the first element of your 2D array which is 10.
Then, by writing `**pArr` in your last `printf` you try to dereference 10 which is in hexadecimal `0xa` thus the error message.

Comment: @Santosh I know this. But, I want to know when I did `int **pArr = arr;` than the value at `pArr` should be equal to the address at `arr`(both in magnitude & type, which is `pointer to pointer to int`). `pArr` holds the value same as the `arr` but of type `pointer to int`. Why?

Comment: @beginner could this be what you're looking for: `int (*pArr)[3] = arr;` ?

Comment: This is `Pointer to Arrays`. I don't think so.

Comment: @beginner how about this then: `int (*pArr)[2][3] = &arr;`? If that's not it I don't know what you want...

Comment: What I want is that on doing `int **pArr = arr;`, `pArr` must hold the same address as in `&arr[]`(which is of type `pointer to pointer to int`), but what is actually happening is that on doing `int **pArr = arr;`, `pArr` holds `&arr[][]`. Why?

Comment: @beginner because it's a 2d array

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int **pArr = arr;
```

To

```
int *Arr = arr;
int **pArr = &Arr;
```

Since `pArr` is a pointer to a pointer of type `int`, you are trying to point it just to a pointer.
so when trying to dereferencing an unknown memory location causes `Segmentation fault`

Edit: 
Consider `int arr[]`; 
Here `&arr` and `arr` are memory location. (arr+2) to get the address of arr[2], but not ((&arr)+2) to do the same. Similarly, `pArr` is pointing to `arr`. When you write `*pArr` it is same as `**arr`

Refer [Please explain the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857698/please-explain-the-difference) for more info

Comment: Please have a look at the comment on the 2nd answer!

Comment: Can you see the difference in the value printed by `*arr` and `*pArr`? the former would print address whereas the latter would dereference the pointer and print the value.

Comment: Of course, I can see the difference. But what I'm asking is, on doing `int **pArr = arr;`, `pArr` is actually holding the `*arr` instead of `arr`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your array `arr` and `pArr` contains address `0x60f914`. The memory here contains 6 integers are you have initialized.

When your do `*pArr` it will give you contains at address `0x60f914` which is `10`. And when you do `**pArr` it will give you contains at address `10`.

So the conclusion is 2-D array is not exactly arranged as _pointer-to-pointer-to-int`.

---

Update:

This is similar to type-casting. If you have some memory address (e.g. `void *`) you can type cast it to anything (`int *` or `my_struct *`) and access the contains of it. But this does not guarantee that structure and contains of that memory is valid for typecasting you are trying to do.

Comment: So, you mean when I do `int **pArr = arr;`, `pArr` holds the address same as `arr` but of type `pointer to int` & not `pointer to pointer to int`? It is true, but why is it happening, that is what I want to know!

Comment: OK, I have tried typecasting as well. I did `int **pArr = (int **)arr;`, but output is same as before. What is the type of value in `pArr` according to you if we use `int **pArr = (int **)arr;`

Answer (score 1):

A multidimensional array is a compiler construct. It is a continuous memory area whose the position is abstracted away by the compiler. A computer's physical memory layout is purely single dimensional (a huge array).

So, this following code:

```
int **pArr = arr;
```

It translates in the following assembly:

```
   6:hhh1.c         ****     int **pArr = arr;
  41                    .loc 1 6 0
  42 0032 488D45E0      leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
  43 0036 488945D8      movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
```

And the following (correct) code:

```
 int (*pArr)[3] = arr;
```

Translates in the following assembly:

```
   6:hhh2.c         ****     int (*pArr)[3] = arr;
  41                    .loc 1 6 0
  42 0032 488D45E0      leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
  43 0036 488945D8      movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
```

Surprised that it translates exactly the same!? It's because the second code changes how the memory is fetch by the compiler later on your code.

Let's take a look in the assembly of the last printf or yours, the first being the one of the wrong code, and the second being from the right code:

```
  14:hhh1.c         ****     printf("\npArr = %d   *pArr = %d **pArr = %d", pArr, *pArr, **pArr);    //EXCEPTION thrown here
  71                    .loc 1 14 0
  72 00a0 488B45D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
  73 00a4 488B00        movq    (%rax), %rax
  74 00a7 8B08          movl    (%rax), %ecx
  75 00a9 488B45D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
  76 00ad 488B10        movq    (%rax), %rdx
  77 00b0 488B45D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
  78 00b4 4889C6        movq    %rax, %rsi
  79 00b7 BF000000      movl    $.LC5, %edi
  79      00
  80 00bc B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
  80      00
  81 00c1 E8000000      call    printf
```

And now, the generated from using the second style:

```
  14:hhh2.c         ****     printf("\npArr = %d   *pArr = %d **pArr = %d", pArr, *pArr, **pArr);    //EXCEPTION thrown here
  71                    .loc 1 14 0
  72 00a0 488B45D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
  73 00a4 8B08          movl    (%rax), %ecx
  74 00a6 488B55D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rdx
  75 00aa 488B45D8      movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
  76 00ae 4889C6        movq    %rax, %rsi
  77 00b1 BF000000      movl    $.LC5, %edi
  77      00
  78 00b6 B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
  78      00
  79 00bb E8000000      call    printf
```

Wow! See now? It's different.

Comment: Now that is a pretty impressive presentation, but frankly I don't understand `assembly`. At least I get to know that `single dimensional` arrays are treated completely different from `multidimensional` arrays by the compiler

Comment: One more thing, how should I assign the address of 2D array to a `int **somePointer;`, if there is some way to do so. Of course `Pointer to Arrays` is one option, but is there any other option to do the same?

Comment: No. If you really want to use the `int **pArr = arr;`, the sole thing that you can do is change the printf, to hint the compiler that the content of the pointer is a memory address, like that `printf("\npArr = %d   *pArr = %d **pArr = %d", pArr, *pArr, &**pArr);`

Comment: So when we do `int **pArr = arr;` or `int **pArr = (int **)arr;` where `arr` could be any `multidimensional array` than the `pArr` would always be holding the `&arr[][]` or `&arr[][][]` depending upon the dimensions and `*pArr` will show `arr[][]` or `arr[][][]`, again depending upon the dimensions of the array. Is that right?

Comment: Just fixing my proposed answer above: i confused multimensional array with a unrelated thing. A multidimensional array is NOT a array of pointers, it is stored contiguous in the memory, and the position is abstracted away by the compiler. The reason that a pointer to a pointer don't work with it is because, as the name implies, it is a pointer (memory address) that must point to a another memory address. Using a pointer to a pointer on a array, you have the the memory address of the first element, and the element itself, not another memory address. Dereferencing it points to nothing.

Comment: Your last comment cleared a lot of confusion. Both your answer & comments are appreciated. Thanks :)